# How can I validate a list which contains floats in a specific range with Cerberus?

Tags: cerberus

I would like to validate JSON objects that were parsed into Python dictionaries like the following:

```py
# example with 2 elements
{
    'coordinates': [-20.3, 30.6]
}

# example with 3 elements
{
    'coordinates': [-20.3, 30.6, 0]
}
```

So far I was able to define the following schema:

```py
schema = {
    'coordinates': {
        'required': True,
        'type': 'list',
        'minlength': 2,
        'maxlength': 3,
        'schema': {
            'type': 'float',
        },
    }
}
```

I would also like to check these constraints:

- the first item of the `coordinates` field's value should be between -30.0 and 10.0
- the second item should be between -10.0 and 50.0

But I was not able to come up with something useful. Does anyone have suggestions how to achieve this?

---

**Update:** Based on accepted answer the schema becomes the following

```py
schema = {
    'coordinates': {
        'required': True,
        'type': 'list',
        "oneof_items": (
            ({"min": -30.0, "max": 10.0}, {"min": -10.0, "max": 50.0}),
            ({"min": -30.0, "max": 10.0}, {"min": -10.0, "max": 50.0}, {}),
        ),
    }
}
```

*docs: https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules-typesaver*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule:

```py
{"oneof_items":
  (
    ({"min": -30.0, "max": 10.0}, {"min": -10.0, "max": 50.0}),
    ({"min": -30.0, "max": 10.0}, {"min": -10.0, "max": 50.0}, {}),
  )
}
```

That makes the length-related rules superfluous. To get rid of the redundancies Python object references or the [rule set registry](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/schemas.html#registries) are feasible.

Comment: thanks! I was hoping for something like this. undocumented feature?

Comment: found it -> https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#of-rules-typesaver
note: never ever I would have figured this out :) thanks!